# Possible to "manually" search a running program's memory?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, memory, troubleshooting, crash

Would it be possible to manually search through a running/active program's memory (in Windows 7)?

Windows just notified me that Firefox "has stopped working" and is asking me to close or debug. I had a number of tabs and important posts I was working on that I'm now about to lose.

Because Firefox's window is now grayed out (with the Close vs Debug option box), I'm wondering if I could manually search through its still-active memory to get the titles/URLs of tabs I had open, possibly even text I was posting. Firefox.exe is still running -- I have yet to click "Close program" or "Debug".

Is there any third-party utility that could accomplish this? Or, might this be doable via the "Debug" option?

Comment: reading or modifying the memory of a running process is prohibited on the OS level (malware, viruses and hackers want to circumvent exactly this). maybe it's better to just look in your browser history...

Comment: For future reference (sorry, no help now!) install the "Session Saver" or a similar add-on, because Firefox's own session-save information is often inadequate & only goes back to the previous session.  You  might have some luck checking your Firefox cache (on disk, under your Firefox profile), to see pages last visited.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552184(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A debugger can look in another process's memory, but finding the information you're looking for could take a very, very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using Debug option as long as you have a development tool like Visual Studio already installed. Operating system would attach VS Debugger to the running process. But even if you get to that point, looking through a process memory is not easy. Even if you have a string for searching, other kind of data could be encoded in more than just one way. And you don't know before that hand.